# как отправить личное сообщение от лица selfbot'a на js

Tags: javascript, discord, бот, sendmessage

имеется рабочий код, нужно чтобы селфбот по id пользователя присылал ему личное сообщение, либо может по ссылке на канал

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js-selfbot-v13');
const { ms } = require('google-translate-api/languages');
const client = new Client(); // All partials are loaded automatically

client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready!`);
});
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
            msg.channel.send('pong');
        }
    }
    
});



client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете смело руководствоваться документацией этой библиотеки:

https://discordjs-self-v13.netlify.app/#/docs/docs/main/general/welcome

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get("<айди>");

// Или если не сработал вариант выше:
const user = await client.users.fetch("<айди пользователям>");

user.send("pong");
```

Comment: Спасибо это работает